# linq min question/bug

Tags: c#, linq

Anyone care to guess what currentIndex is at the end of execution?

```
        int[] ints = new int[] { -1, 12, 26, 41, 52, -1, -1 };
        int minInt = ints.Min();
```

It's 110. Does anyone know why?

Wrapped it a main function below

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
class Sample {
public static void Main() 
{

    int[] ints = new int[] { -1, 12, 26, 41, 52, -1, -1 };
    int minInt = ints.Min();
    Console.WriteLine(minInt);
 }
}
```

EDIT: I changed the variable name to minInt from currentIndex. It was a copy and paste from an function I'm debugging, which made sense in that context but not so much here.

Comment: Can you provide a small, complete program that demonstrates the behaviour? This isn't enough to make a diagnosis.

Comment: This should be everything that is needed.

Comment: Min is not the index, it is the smallest item in the list. How you get 110, is beyond me though. Also, your code does not compile. Missing `using System.Linq;` ?

Comment: Yeah it's missing that namespace.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. I just copied and pasted the above code into a new console application, and it prints -1 as expected.

Comment: With the same repro, it's also returning -1. If I copy and paste the two lines and place it in my function, it's returning 110. I might just close this question, since I can't make a good repro.

Comment: I once spent a couple of hours trying to figure out why a particular VBScript program gave a crazy result. And then I realized that some strange person had defined a local variable called "InStr" which was shadowing the function of the same name. You've got something crazy going on. Don't ignore crazy stuff like that; get to the bottom of it. Otherwise you're just leaving a time bomb in the code for someone else to set off in the future.

Comment: I *think* that the issue was due to local variable to a member variable. I've noticed that in .NET that unless you read to a variable you wrote to, you can really debug it, meaning you can't local at the value of the variable. Something like this probably happened. It was a saturday night and I was working on my one man fun project while drinking beer, so I'm too worried.  I changed the code so that I don't run into issue anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too long for a comment, but here is what I get.

```
C:\>copy con t.cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
class Sample {
public static void Main()
{

    int[] ints = new int[] { -1, 12, 26, 41, 52, -1, -1 };
    int minInt = ints.Min();
    Console.WriteLine(minInt);
 }
}
^Z
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\>csc t.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2008 Compiler version 3.5.30729.4926
for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework version 3.5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


C:\>t
-1

C:\>
```

Comment: Look for another function called `Min`  :)  I suspect you have another extension method getting preferred to the Linq one.

Comment: I looked and even tried to step into the function, no dice :(

Comment: I think it had to something with a local variable in a function having the same name as a member variable of the class. I'll just work around the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It should be -1. Also, I think the "currentIndex" variable naming is misleading. It is actually the minimum value in the array and not the current index. For example, if you add -2 in that array, the variable currentIndex in the above example would be -2.

Comment: Right the variable name makes no sense in this context, it's a copy and paste. This is returning 110 though, which is confusing me to say the least.

Comment: Do you maybe have another extension method called `Min` ?

Comment: No. I'm not sure what is going on.